# How to fetch average rows per day?

Tags: mysql, average

I have a table

```
id | created
---------------
 1 | 2014-07-01
 2 | 2014-07-01
 3 | 2014-07-01
 4 | 2014-07-01
 5 | 2014-07-02
 6 | 2014-07-03
 7 | 2014-07-04
 8 | 2014-07-05
 9 | 2014-07-05
10 | 2014-07-05
```

and I want to fetch the average of rows per day. So if it's

```
2014-07-01: 4 rows
2014-07-02: 1 row
2014-07-03: 1 row
2014-07-04: 1 row
2014-07-05: 3 rows
```

The average would be

```
sum 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 = 10 items
10 items / 5 days = 2 items/day
```

My SQL query is

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT(*))
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY `created`
```

But I get this error

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

How do I have to modify my query in order to get a correct result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without subquery also.It is much fatser.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT `created`) FROM `mytable`;
```

Here is the example link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c284df/2

Answer (score 4):

You need to put it in a subquery.

```
SELECT AVG(my_count) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) as my_count
FROM
your_table
GROUP BY created
) sq
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7b5ac/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub query to get the count per day, and then use that to get the average:-

```
SELECT AVG(day_count)
FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS day_count
    FROM `mytable`
    GROUP BY `created`
) sub0
```